# Jinja template is not rendering Date object in javascript properly

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am currently using Flask, and I have a Unix timestamp that I am trying to send to a template. In this template, I plan to convert the Unix timestamp to a more readable format using the Date object in javascript.

Basically, I send the timestamp as a parameter through the render_template method. I then have javascript imbedded into my HTML page through the script tag, where I set a span element to the timestamp converted to the readable format. Here is how it is done:

In my flask app:

```
now = datetime.now()
unix_timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)

return render_template("page.html", timestamp=unix_timestamp)
```

In my template:

```
<span id="time"></span>
<script language="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date({{timestamp * 1000}}).toString();
</script>
```

I expect the span element to be set to a date. However, it is blank. Also, when I run the innerHTML line from the console with the rendered timestamp, it sets it correctly. Actually, it isn't really correct. As a separate issue, the date is set incorrectly. I wanted the span tag to basically render the current time correctly, but it is not happening.

Comment: Couldn't it be easier to format it directly in the span block ? why do you need to use JS here ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the Date object needs to be used in order to convert from Unix to standard time, right? How would I convert it without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `now` directly? You don't need to use JS to display dates.

```
now = datetime.now()
return render_template("page.html", now=now)
```

template:

```
<span id="time">{{ now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</span>
{# use iso format #}
<span id="time">{{ now.isoformat() }}</span>
```

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime
- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: I would like the unix timestamp itself to be sent, if possible.